# App security breach - how to invalidate all the tokens for one app?

Tags: facebook, security, access-token, app-secret

One of our apps got hacked and some wall posts/photos are posted on
behalf of our app. We are suspecting that a hacker has somehow retrieved access_token from our app.

What's the best way to plug this security breach?

We want to invalidate all the access token for that app.
But the question is how? Does changing the app secret help on this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All access tokens are invalidated when you change your App Secret, [according to Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/).

Comment: We changed our app secrets, and we see that the hacker is still posting things on our behalf... what else can we do?

Comment: First of all, have you made __sure__ that he does __not__ have access to your app any more? (Whatever that may have meant in the first place – access to a developers FB account, to your apps own code, …)